# Second derivative of $\sec(3x)\sqrt{324\cos^2(3x) + 396 + 121\sec^2(3x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to take second derivative of $$\sec(3x)\sqrt{324\cos^2(3x) + 396 + 121\sec^2(3x)}.$$

I am having trouble with taking the second derivative of this. I know I should simplify it before taking the derivative but I'm not sure how to do that.

The final part is I have to find the second derivative at $\pi/12$ , but my main question is how I would simplify $$\sec(3x)\sqrt{324\cos^2(3x) + 396 + 121\sec^2(3x)}$$ before taking the derivative.
$0 < x < \frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if we set $$u = \sec 3x,$$ then the quantity in the radical is
$$\frac{324}{u^2} + 396 + 121 u^2,$$ which turns out to be a perfect square of a rational expression---can you see how to find it??